# 3D: avoid pinching at poles when creating sphere from polar coordinates

Tags: math, three.js, geometry, quaternions, polar-coordinates

I'm using Wikipedia's [spherical coordinate system article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) to create a sphere made out of particles in Three.js. Based on this article, I created a small `Polarizer` class that takes in polar coordinates with `setPolar(rho, theta, phi)` and it returns its corresponding x, y, z

Here's the `setPolar()` function:

```
// Rho: radius
// theta θ: polar angle on Y axis
// phi φ: azimuthal angle on Z axis

Polarizer.prototype.setPolar = function(rho, theta, phi){
  // Limit values to zero
  this.rho = Math.max(0, rho);
  this.theta = Math.max(0, theta);
  this.phi = Math.max(0, phi);

  // Calculate x,y,z
  this.x = this.rho * Math.sin(this.theta) * Math.sin(this.phi);
  this.y = this.rho * Math.cos(this.theta);
  this.z = this.rho * Math.sin(this.theta) * Math.cos(this.phi);

  return this;
}
```

I'm using it to position my particles as follows:

```
var tempPolarizer = new Polarizer();

for(var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++){
  tempPolarizer.setPolar(
    50,                         // Radius of 50
    Math.random() * Math.PI,    // Theta ranges from 0 - PI
    Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI // Phi ranges from 0 - 2PI
  );

  // Set new vertex positions
  geometry.vertices[i].set(
    tempPolarizer.x,
    tempPolarizer.y,
    tempPolarizer.z
  );
}
```

It works wonderfully, except that I'm getting high particle densities, or "pinching" at the poles:

[image: PolarPinching]

I'm stumped as to how to avoid this from happening. I thought of passing a weighted random number to the latitude, but I'm hoping to animate the particles without the longitude also slowing down and bunching up at the poles.

Is there a different formula to generate a sphere where the poles don't get as much weight? Should I be using quaternions instead?

Comment: I would look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531827/random-point-on-a-given-sphere for two possible solutions and also, more generally, icosahedron sphere is an  extra in three.js which may be useful depending on how you need to test your noise distribution. Example: https://codepen.io/Mombasa/pen/fvgqb

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Comment: @Radio, that's exactly what I was looking for! I had to use something akin to a weighted random number generator that had a higher likelihood to land closer to 0.5 than to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid high density at the poles, I had to lower the likelihood of theta (latitude) landing close to 0 and PI. My input of

`Math.random() * Math.PI,` for theta gives an equal likelihood to all values (orange).

`Math.acos((Math.random() * 2) - 1)` perfectly weights the output to make 0 and PI less likely along the sphere's surface (yellow)

[image]

[image]

Now I can't even tell where the poles are!

Answer (score 2):

1. **For random uniform sampling**

   use random point in unit cube , handle it as vector and set its length to radius of your sphere. For example something like this in C++:

   ```cpp
   x = 2.0*Random()-1.0; 
   y = 2.0*Random()-1.0; 
   z = 2.0*Random()-1.0; 
   m=r/sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
   x*=m;
   y*=m;
   z*=m;
   ```

   where Random return number in `<0.0,1.0>`. For more info see:

   - [Procedural generation of stars with skybox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38068390/2521214)
2. **For uniform non-random sampling**

   see related **QA**s:

   - [Sphere triangulation by mesh subdivision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214)
   - [Make a sphere with equidistant vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25031737/2521214)